# Unable to lauch browser instance when setting the capabilities for download directory in application.properties file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, qaf

I'm using application properties file to set the capabilities of the chrome drive. Below is the code for that initially it worked fine but when I added "download.default_directory": "${dir.downloads}" it's not loading the driver as well.

```
dir.currentdirectory= ${expr:java.lang.System.getProperty("user.dir")}
dir.screenshots = ${dir.currentdirectory}\\resources\\screenshots
dir.downloads = ${dir.currentdirectory}\\resources\\downloads 
chrome.additional.capabilities={"browserName":"chrome","goog:chromeOptions": {"args": ["start-maximized", "--disable-popup-blocking", "disable-infobars", "--disable-extensions"], "extensions": [], "prefs": {"download.directory_upgrade": "true", "download.default_directory": "${dir.downloads}", "download.prompt_for_download": "false", "safebrowsing.enabled": "true"}}}
```

I tried access that value using below code to check the string and its showing correct value.
Not sure why its not loading.

```
String myString = getBundle().getString("chrome.additional.capabilities");
System.out.println("=============="+myString);
```

Comment: could you please check this one @user861594

Comment: what is the output from sysout? Make sure that capability value is valid json string, also don't quote boolean values for instance use `false`, `true` instead of `"false"` or `"true"` in capability value.

Comment: @user861594 
Thanks for your reply.

Below line is displaying in the sysout
{"goog:chromeOptions": {"args": ["start-maximized", "--disable-popup-blocking", "disable-infobars", "--disable-extensions"], "extensions": [], "prefs": {"download.directory_upgrade": "true", "download.default_directory": "*:\\*\\*\\*\resources\downloads", "download.prompt_for_download": "false", "safebrowsing.enabled": "true"}}}

Just added * to mask the actual path

Comment: don't quote boolean values for instance use false, true instead of "false" or "true" in capability value.

Comment: Yeah, tried with removing quotes for boolean values. The result is same unable to launch browser.

Answer (score 0):

Following works fine for me:

```
dir.currentdirectory= ${expr:java.lang.System.getProperty("user.dir")}
dir.screenshots = ${dir.currentdirectory}/resources/screenshots
dir.downloads = ${dir.currentdirectory}/resources/downloads 
chrome.additional.capabilities={"browserName":"chrome","goog:chromeOptions": {"args": ["start-maximized", "--disable-popup-blocking", "disable-infobars", "--disable-extensions"], "extensions": [], "prefs": {"download.directory_upgrade": true, "download.default_directory": "${dir.downloads}", "download.prompt_for_download": false, "safebrowsing.enabled": true}}}
```

If you want to use `\\` add addition `\` for each `\` because `\` is escape char in properties file. For instance for `a\b` you need to set `a\\b` and for `a\\b` you need to set `a\\\\b`. Considering this you can also try as below:

```
dir.screenshots = ${dir.currentdirectory}\\\\resources\\\\screenshots.
```

As a side not you can use any [system properties](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/different_ways_of_providing_prop.html) directly with configuration manager (so as parameter) and system properties has highest prority. So you don't need to use `expr` for to access system property. You can directly refer it as parameter. For example:

```
dir.screenshots = ${user.dir}/resources/screenshots
dir.downloads = ${user.dir}/resources/downloads
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I tried with your suggestions. But still unable to launch chrome.
Getting this error Unable to create driver instance in 1st attempt with retry timeout of 0 seconds. You can check/set value of 'driver.init.retry.timeout' appropriately to set retry timeout on driver initialization failure.com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 245 path $..prefs.download.default_directory

Comment: it clearly states `MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object`. Try that worked for me provided in answer.